# Range "view" that modifies the assigned value

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, std-ranges

I'm implementing a number of audio effects on an embedded platform. From the hardware I get an input buffer of samples in a format that needs some massaging <sup>1</sup>, then there's the process itself, followed by further massaging. There will be several different types of effects, but for now you can think that the actual `process` -function is given as a template parameter <sup>2</sup>.

I'd like to extract to massaging out so that there's no (source) code duplication, and also without having to copy to a separate buffer. Furthermore, while most effects will operate on float-in float-out, I'd like to have the option for a process to work on integers directly. So, using an as-yet-mythical syntax, it would ideally look something like:

```
class Effect1
{
    void process(AudioBuffers<float, float> buffers)
    {
        // A simple case, in and out buffers are processed in lockstep
        for (auto && [in, out] : buffers)
        {
            // Note that "in" is massaged lazily, i.e. on this line
            // to a float, and out is clamped and converted to int
            // on assign
            out = doSomething(in);
        }
    }
};

class Effect2
{
    void process(AudioBuffers<uint32_t, int32_t> buffers)
    {
        // A completely silly effect, just to demonstrate random access
        // and no conversion
        std::size_t k = buffers.out.size() / 2;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < buffers.in.size(); ++i)
        {
            buffers.out[k] = buffers.in[i]; // No need for conversion, we're just shuffling samples
            k = k + 1 < buffers.out.size() ? k + 1 : 0;
        }
    }
};

...

template<typename InputType, typename OutputType>
AudioBuffers
{
     // Note that the constructor arguments are always the types as provided
     // by hardware, so they don't depend on the template arguments
     AudioBuffers(std::array<const uint32_t, kBufferLength> &in, std::array<int32_t, kBufferLength> &out)
     {
       ...
     }
     // Implementation. Here we know the requested InputType and OutputType,
     // so we can insert the necessary massaging when constructing iterators...
     ...
}

...
template<class Effect>
void process(std::array<const uint32_t, kBufferLength> &in, std::array<int32_t, kBufferLength> &out, Effect &effect)
{   
    // Use CTAD to determine the correct instantiation/specialization of AudioBuffers which does the necessary massaging, as determined by the class Effect.
    effect.process({in, out});
}
```

I can certainly implement the AudioBuffer template in "brute force" -style:

1. basically implement iterators for the input and output which do the massaging on dereference and assign on input and output, respectively
2. wrap the input and output buffers in a class that provides `begin` and `end` returning these iterators, and an `operator[]` for random access
3. provide a `begin` and `end` in `AudioBuffers` returning a zip (which I'll have to implement / import an implementation of, since `std::zip` is C++23) of these iterators.
4. Possibly some more boilerplate to get all the deductions to go right

However, I get the feeling that what I want is *almost* a reimplementation of parts of std::ranges and views. I *think* I can do the wrapping of the input buffer by using `std::views::transform`. However, I can't figure out how to wrap the output such that an extra processing step (and type conversion) is done on assign using elements from `std::ranges`.

Finally, **my question**: can I build the functionality described above somehow by combining elements that are already there in `std` or `std::ranges`? If not, anything to simplify implementing the iterators, which would be entirely boilerplate except for derefence / assign? Any other suggestions or maybe frame challenges?

**Footnotes:**

1. specifically, input is 24 bit ints except that the sign bit is not extended above the  24th bit, and output needs to be clamped to 24-bit int range and converted from float to int. Regarding the "just shuffling samples" example above, the output's bits above the 24th have no effect, anything goes.
2. The actual implementation will be an `std::variant<Effect1, Effect2, ...>`  which is `visit`ed.

Comment: what exactly is the functionality you need? "massaging" ?!?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai that doesn't really matter here, the point of the question is to be able to insert the function that does the massaging (just a fancy word for modifying) so that it does not have to be explicitly implemented in the Effect::process -function, but that the compiler has the chance to inline it to the same loop.

In case you're interested, for now the "massaging" is an in-word sign extend from 24 to 32 bits, collecting some statistics, and then clamping the output, as I mention in footnote 1.

I've also already got a working and tested implementation of that.

Comment: "Finally, my question: can I build the functionality described above " it matters what funcitonality you describe. I read the text twice but I didnt understand it

Comment: Ah, sorry, I though you were asking about the "massaging" part. I want to wrap an of std::array<uint32_t> such that when dereferencing, the result is an int32_t modified in a specific way. That I think I can do with views::transform. The other part is that I want to assign to a range such that I'm assigning a float, and the float gets converted to an int32_t and modified in another specific way. This while hiding the details from the code doing the dereferencing and assigning. Most of the long text tries to explain why I would like to do that in the first place.